# After inserting data I get redirected to the json file, not to the view - because of dropdown list

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

EDIT: The problem is that the AddOrView view is calling the jquery script because of the chosen js file that I am using for my DropDown.
When I remove this part, it is working. But AddOrView is not using my default _Layout that has all the scripts referenced.

How can I get past that?

I have a view that displays data with the jQuery DataTable. There I have a button for inserting new Data in it. My goal is to insert the data with the popup, and after that to come back to the view with the table and display a message.
I have managed to do that on other forms, and it works. But on this form I have a DropDownList with some values that is used for inserting. And when I have them in the view, after adding records, I cannot manage to go back to the view. It proccedes viewing json file in my browser.

Maybe I need to use redirect to action in my controller? So far, I have benn returning json, and it worked. But I didn't have any DropDownLists.

I know that the DropDownList is causing the problem, because when I use text fields and insert ID as a number, everything works fine.

Do I need to change my approach, and use ajax calls for this post method?
Or something else?

This is my popup form for adding records:

```
@model aspEvidencijaZgrada.Models.UnosUplata

@{
    Layout = null;
}
<h2 style="text-align:center">Uplate</h2>
<hr />
<br />
<br />

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddOrEdit", "UnosUplata", FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "return SubmitForm(this)" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal" style="padding-left:150px;">

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.zgrada_id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.zgrada_id, new SelectList(Model.ZgradaCollection, "ID", "naziv"), "Izaberite zgradu", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddlZgradaU" })

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.zgrada_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.korisnik_id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.korisnik_id, new SelectList(" "), " Izaberite korisnika ", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddlKorisnikU" })


                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.korisnik_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.mesec, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.mesec, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.mesec, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.godina, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.godina, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.godina, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="form-group" style="padding-left:150px;">
            <input type="submit" value="Sacuvaj" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-right:25px;" />
            <input type="reset" value="Ponisti" class="btn" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {


        $("#ddlKorisnikU").chosen();

        $("#ddlZgradaU").chosen();

        $("#ddlZgradaU").change(function () {
            //alert("oi" + $("#ddlZgradaU").val());
            $.get("/UnosUplata/GetKorisnik", { idZgrade: $("#ddlZgradaU").val() }, function (data) {

                $("#ddlKorisnikU").empty();

                $("#ddlKorisnikU").append("<option> Izaberite korisnika </option>");
                $.each(data, function (index, row) {

                    $("#ddlKorisnikU").append("<option value='" + row.ID + "'>" + row.imePrezime + "</option>");
                    $("#ddlKorisnikU").trigger("chosen:updated");
                });


            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

This is my controller :

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddOrEdit(int id = 0)
    {
        UnosUplata model = new UnosUplata();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        if (id == 0)
            return View(new UnosUplata());
        else
        {
            using (conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
            {
                //return View(GetAll().Find(Zgr => Zgr.ID == id));
                using (conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    string query = "SELECT * FROM UnosUplata WHERE ID=@id";
                    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
                    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                    sda.Fill(dt);


                }
                if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
                {

                    model.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][0]);
                    model.zgrada_id = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][1]);
                    model.korisnik_id = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][2]);
                    model.mesec = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][3]);
                    model.godina = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][4]);
                    model.iznos = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[0][5]);
                    model.datum = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0][6]);


                }
                return View(model);

            }

        }

    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddOrEdit(UnosUplata model)
    {
        try
        {
            using (conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
            {

                if (model.ID != 0)
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    string query = "UPDATE UnosUplata SET zgrada_id=@zgrada_id, korisnik_id=@korisnik_id, mesec=@mesec,godina=@godina,iznos=@iznos,datum=@datum WHERE ID=@id";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", model.ID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zgrada_id", model.zgrada_id);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@korisnik_id", model.korisnik_id);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mesec", (object)model.mesec ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@godina", (object)model.godina ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iznos", (object)model.iznos ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datum", (object)model.datum ?? DBNull.Value);

                    return Json(new { success = true, message = "Update uspesan" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


                }

                else
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    string query = "INSERT INTO UnosUplata (zgrada_id,korisnik_id,mesec,godina,iznos,datum) VALUES(@zgrada_id,@korisnik_id,@mesec,@godina,@iznos,@datum)";

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);


                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zgrada_id", model.zgrada_id);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@korisnik_id", model.korisnik_id);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mesec", (object)model.mesec ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@godina", (object)model.godina ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iznos", (object)model.iznos ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datum", (object)model.datum ?? DBNull.Value);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                    return Json(new { success = true, message = "Uspesno sacuvano" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, message = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }



    }
```

and this is my Index Page:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Unos uplata";

}

<h2 style="text-align:center">Zgrade</h2>
<br />


<a class="btn btn-success" style="margin-bottom:10px" onclick="PopupForm('@Url.Action("AddOrEdit","UnosUplata")')"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Dodaj novi</a>
<br />
<table id="uplateTable" class="table table-striped table-condensed" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>zgrada_id</th>
            <th>korisnik_id</th>
            <th>mesec broj</th>
            <th>godina</th>


            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

@section scripts{
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var Popup, dataTable;
        $(document).ready(function () {
           // alert("aa");
            dataTable = $("#uplateTable").DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/UnosUplata/GetData",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "zgrada_id" },
                    { "data": "korisnik_id" },
                    { "data": "mesec" },
                    { "data": "godina" },



                    {"data": "ID" , "render" : function (data) {
                        return "<a class='btn btn-default btn-sm' onclick=PopupForm('@Url.Action("AddOrEdit","Zgrada")/" + data + "')><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> Izmena</a><a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' style='margin-left:5px' onclick=Delete("+data+")><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Brisanje</a>";
                    },
                        "orderable": false,
                        "searchable":false,
                        "width":"150px"
                    }

                ],
                "language": {
                    "search": "Pretraga:",
                    "sLengthMenu": "Prikazi _MENU_ stavki",
                    "info": "Stranica broj _PAGE_ od _PAGES_",
                    "emptyTable" : "Nema podataka"
                }
            });
        });
              function PopupForm(url) {
                  var formDiv = $('<div/>');
                  $.get(url)
                      .done(function (response) {
                          formDiv.html(response);
                          Popup = formDiv.dialog({
                              autoOpen: true,
                              resozable: false,
                              title: "Podaci o zgradi",
                              height: 600,
                              width: 800,
                              open: function (event, ui) {
                                  $('.ui-dialog').css('overflow-x', 'hidden');
                                  $('.ui-dialog-content').css('overflow-x', 'hidden');


                              },


                              close: function () {
                                  $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
                                  Popup.dialog('destroy').remove();
                              }
                          });
                      });
              }


              function SubmitForm(form) {
                  $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
                  if ($(form).valid()) {
                      $.ajax({
                          type: "POST",
                          url: form.action,
                          data: $(form).serialize(),
                          success: function (data) {
                              if (data.success) {
                                  Popup.dialog('close');
                                  dataTable.ajax.reload();
                                  $.notify(data.message, {
                                      globalPosition: "top center",
                                      className: "success"
                                  });



                              }
                              else {
                                  $.notify(data.message, "error");
                              }
                          }
                      });
                  }
                  return false;
              }
         function Delete(id) {
             alertify.confirm('Evidencija uplata', 'Zelite da obrisete ovaj podatak?', function () {
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("Delete","UnosUplata")/' + id,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.success) {
                            dataTable.ajax.reload();
                            $.notify(data.message, {
                                globalPosition: "top center",
                                className: "success"
                            });

                        }
                    }
                });

        }, null);
        }

    </script>
}
```